# idangero Swiper vs React with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, swiper.js, idangero

Good morning everyone!

I'm trying to use the idangero's Swiper in my React project with Typescript and Visual Studio code... but it can't even be imported!

If I import it using:

```
import Swiper from 'swiper';
```

VS code return:

```
[ts] Module ''swiper'' has no default export.
```

If I import it using:

```
import * as Swiper from 'swiper';
```

VS code return:

```
[ts] Module ''swiper'' resolves to a non-module entity and cannot be imported using this construct.
```

If I import it using:

```
import * as Swiper from 'swiper/dist/js/swiper.js';
```

VS code return (obviusly):

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'swiper/dist/js/swiper.js'. '/Users/luca/CEFLA/workspace-web/autoclave-web/node_modules/swiper/dist/js/swiper.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

Try `npm install @types/swiper` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'swiper';`

I've already add to my ts config these lines as seen on similar question find around the web:

```
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
"esModuleInterop": true,
```

But nothing is changed.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: After installing the latest versions of the `swiper` and `@types/swiper` packages, `import Swiper from "swiper";` is compiling successfully for me with both TypeScript 2.9.2 and 3.0.1.  What TypeScript version and what versions of the packages are you using?

Comment: Latest Swiper, latest @types/swiper, Typescript 2.9.2. I've also made a try with latest @types/swiper and his version of Swiper but it give me the same error.

Comment: Can you run `tsc` with the `--traceResolution` option and add the output to the question?  That might give me a hint about what is happening.

Comment: I've managed an ad hoc solution. I've installed the react-id-swiper (who is the react version of idangero Swiper), installed the @types/swiper d.ts and then I've created quick (really really really quick and noob) d.ts for react-id-swiper. Now it works.